# Replace WCF Service with ServiceStack without Changing Client Code

Tags: wcf, servicestack

I'm looking at replacing our WCF services with ServiceStack. I know it supports SOAP endpoints, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to structure the service so that we don't have to change the client code. We have a third party that calls our services, and having them change their code is out of the question.

For example, if we have a service called Test.svc with an action called DoStuff, how would I structure a ServiceStack replacement that will respond to requests on the same Urls as the WCF service?

Is there a way to do this?